# How can I use Calendar in my iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios

I have an application of TimeTracker. I want to add a calendar for showing Reports. As I know that XCode/iOS doesn't provide any calendar tool(like Date Picker).What should I use ?

Thanks

EDIT : Thanks for the quick response guys (Mayur , John and Yoko). It's really pretty tough to accept one answer while everyone's answer is almost same.

Regards
Akshay

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084991/how-to-show-full-calendar-picker-in-ios

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

These are the option I am aware of:

1) http://tapku.com/

2) http://github.com/klazuka/Kal

3) http://code.google.com/p/iphonecal (needs to be customized - easily - to change text from chinese to english)

4) Commercial: http://nrg.com.bd/blog/archives/36 but the look & feel of the previous ones is much, much better and they are free, if you can comply with their licenses.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Yoko - The First link is not working. :(
2)Kal is a good thing. Looking into it.
Thanks  :)

Comment: Have changed it now. You can see that also.