# How To Show full Calendar picker in iOS

Tags: ios, ui-calendar

**I need a calendar picker when button is click then show me a popup calendar view and set selected date in label**

[image]

**I need a that type in popup view**

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Buy i doesn't no what code i will write.. i am using third party code

Comment: ok which thirdparty are you used

Comment: https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar